# Postgres CREATE TABLE never finishes + bad db connections

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

Every day I drop and create a postgres table using a python ETL cronjob, with roughly the same size. The action takes around 12 minutes, but on some days, it takes many hours and never finishes.

When I check the connections in pgadmin, I see some in red.
[image]

Killing these connections and restarting the job does the trick but I want to prevent this from happening in the first place.

Comment: I have no idea what pgAdmin4 decides to color red.  If your question depends on knowing the intimate workings of pgAdmin4, you should tag your question as such.

Comment: What are the queries?  What are the plans for the queries?

Comment: Also, what type of disk subsystem is postgresql running on. Wonder if there is a disk I/O bottleneck neck when it occurs for hours and you have to force kill. Could be a combination of a bunch of things.